# Where is iTunes SDK/API documentation?

Tags: c#, c++, itunes, itunes-sdk

I downloaded a zipped archive from Apple that consists of a C++ header file and source. Included in this was a help file. For some reason this help file opens but I cannot read the content. Is there any other documentation outside of a help file for this? For c++ or c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved.. The problem was a Windows Security feature was blocking the compiled help file from opening. I found the solution here:

http://weblog.helpware.net/?p=36

Answer (score 27):

If you are on Windows, you probably are looking for the "iTunes COM for Windows SDK".

Get a free ADC login [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/register/) if you haven't done so already.  Once you have done that, you can go to http://connect.apple.com and log in.

Click on "Developer Tools", and somewhere in the massive list of results is "iTunes COM for Windows SDK".  Download that, it's just an ordinary zip file, and somewhere in there is a directory named iTunesCOMWindowsSDK.  In that directory, there is a iTunesCOM.chm file that contains all the reference material you need.

If this is the help file you already have, you could consider decompiling the chm file using the hh.exe tool that comes with Windows.

Comment: Yes.. this is the same zip that I have. The issue I have is that the help file contains the TOC but selecting a topic does not display anything in the right side pane. I tried using the hh.exe from the command line (as you suggested) but haven't had any luck. I have never used this utility before. I tried this: hh.exe mk:@MSITSTore:{pathtohelp}::/main.html

It just seemed to open the help file but with the same results..

Comment: This answer seems to be out dated?

Comment: @StevenByrne - yes this is outdated, see my answer.

Comment: It's still there as of today. The zip file also contains a chm with documentation which seems to be slightly more up-to-date than in the answer from @Hogan

Comment: @Lennart -- I don't see it, where is it exactly?

Comment: @Hogan Not sure if a direct link works: https://download.developer.apple.com/Applications/iTunes_COM_for_Windows_SDK/iTunes_COM_9.1.0.80.zip Otherwise here's a screenshot: https://imgur.com/HdseSYo

Answer (score 11):

It seems the only source for the iTunes COM documentation is now archived on github by https://stackoverflow.com/users/188792/joshkunz

The nice web page is here

http://www.joshkunz.com/iTunesControl/

And the github project is here

https://github.com/Joshkunz/iTunesControl

Comment: this is really all documentation needed

Comment: @spankmaster79 - except for new features that are not documented in the COM (or does exist).  For example, changing the media type.  I'd **LOVE** to hear from someone who knows the API for that.

Comment: and I'd love a tool like tune-instructor on windows... so let's start developing something like it and find out what iTunes actually can do in Windows

Comment: Also rather that coding in C++/C#, try Javascript (dual COM interfaces be praised). Here is an example to get you inspired: http://projects.nateweiss.com/nwdc/itunes/scripts/

For example, here is a cscript to add a file to the library:

```
var iTunesApp = WScript.CreateObject("iTunes.Application");
var mainPlaylist = iTunesApp.LibraryPlaylist;
mainPlaylist.AddFile(path);
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this is not relevant but it feels like this code complements the question nicely - I would have put this in comments but comments don't seem to allow code formatting (d'uh).

Anyway, here is a C# example of how to dump all songs in the library:

```
dynamic iTunesApplication = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("iTunes.Application"));
dynamic mainPlaylist = iTunesApplication.LibraryPlaylist;
for (int i = 1; i <= mainPlaylist.Tracks.Count; i++)
{
  dynamic track = mainPlaylist.Tracks.Item(i);
  Console.WriteLine(track.Location);
}
```

Thanks to Hogan for the [great pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18370658/497403) to the documentation!